# Value of a double integration

Tags: integration

How to prove that

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\int_{y}^\infty x\ f(x,y;r)dx +\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\int_{-\infty}^y y\ f(x,y;r)dx =\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{1-r}{\pi}}$ where
$f(x,y;r)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-r^2}}\exp\left[-\frac{x^2+y^2-2rxy}{2(1-r^2)}\right]$ .

Comment: Please edit your question to include any workings of your own.

Comment: According to Maple the value of the integral is $\sqrt{\dfrac{1-r}{\pi}}$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right @JanG

Comment: @Bacon: I have used the transformation $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$ so that $J=1/2$ and $x^2-2rxy+y^2=\frac{1}{2}(1-r)u^2+\frac{1}{2}(1-r)v^2 $. What will the limits of  $u$ and $v$?

Comment: $@$user315228. I don't think that you have to do any transformations. If you use the error function ${\rm erf}$ then you can calculate $\displaystyle \int_{y}^{\infty}xf(x,y;r)\, dx + \int_{-\infty}^{y}yf(x,y;r)\, dx$.  Finally the error function will disappear if you integrate by parts with respect to $y$.